# Recursive Fibonacci in text WebAssembly

Tags: recursion, webassembly

I've been playing around with text WebAssembly and wanted to write a recursive Fibonacci number calculator.

I got a version that works but it uses a single branch if statement to check for the base case:

```
(module
 (export "fib" (func $fib))
  (func $fib (param $0 i32) (result i32)
  (if
   (i32.lt_s
    (get_local $0)
    (i32.const 2)
   )
   (return
    (i32.const 1)
   )
  )
  (return
   (i32.add
    (call $fib
    (i32.sub
      (get_local $0)
      (i32.const 2)
    )
   )
    (call $fib
      (i32.sub
       (get_local $0)
       (i32.const 1)
     )
    )
   )
  )
 )
)
```

I tested this in wabt here: https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wat2wasm/

I tried to rewrite this using select conditional:

```
(module
       (export "fib" (func $fib))
     (func $fib (param $0 i32) (result i32)
            (select
                   (return
                    (i32.const 1)
                    )
                  (return
                   (i32.add
                    (call $fib
                          (i32.sub
                           (get_local $0)
                           (i32.const 2)
                           )
                          )
                    (call $fib
                          (i32.sub
                           (get_local $0)
                           (i32.const 1)
                           )
                          )
                    )
                   )
                (i32.lt_s
                 (get_local $0)
                 (i32.const 2))))
     )
```

This compiles to .wasm, but it does not run as expected, just returning the base case. I tried similar versions with if-then-else, but to no avail. Why would the result of a single-branch if be any different from a two-branch conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just gave me a reason to learn wasm. I can't yet answer your question about the single-branch `if`, but I can show you a working `fib` function.

```scm
(module
  (func $fib2 (param $n i32) (param $a i32) (param $b i32) (result i32)
    (if (result i32)
        (i32.eqz (local.get $n))
        (then (local.get $a))
        (else (call $fib2 (i32.sub (local.get $n)
                                   (i32.const 1))
                          (local.get $b)
                          (i32.add (local.get $a)
                                   (local.get $b))))))

  (func $fib (param i32) (result i32)
    (call $fib2 (local.get 0)
                (i32.const 0)   ;; seed value $a
                (i32.const 1))) ;; seed value $b

  (export "fib" (func $fib)))
```

Copy/paste to demo it [here](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wat2wasm/)

```js
const wasmInstance =
  new WebAssembly.Instance (wasmModule, {})

const { fib } =
  wasmInstance.exports

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
  console.log (fib (x))
```

Output

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

For what it's worth, the implementation here is quite different than yours. Your program requires exponential computational time and space whereas the above program's requirements are linear.

This is evident by examining your use of `(call $fib ...)`. In your program, a single call to `$fib` has the possibility to spawn *two* additional calls to `$fib`, which each have the possibility to spawn *two* more calls to `$fib`, and on and on. Above `$fib2` only has potential to call itself *once*, at most.

---

Although it has a lesser performance, of course it is still *possible* to implement the exponential process

```scm
(module
  (func $fib (param $n i32) (result i32)
    (if (result i32)
        (i32.lt_s (local.get $n)
                  (i32.const 2))
        (then (local.get $n))
        ;; recursive branch spawns _two_ calls to $fib; not ideal
        (else (i32.add (call $fib (i32.sub (local.get $n)
                                           (i32.const 1)))
                       (call $fib (i32.sub (local.get $n)
                                           (i32.const 2)))))))

  (export "fib" (func $fib)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the working example. I wonder if the reason for failure to compile text WASM to bytecode WASM is some sort of compiler optimization that does not like the inefficient recursion. The reason for insisting on the brute force recursion was trying to make a toy transpiler to WASM. What confused me was the many ways in which conditionals can be written and how parenthesis could be applied to AST nodes.

Comment: I found [*Writing WebAssembly By Hand*](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/04/26/webassembly-by-hand.html) to be very helpful. I also made an update to my answer. This is a neat little language. Thanks for sharing your question :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `select` is not a conditional: it *always* evaluates all its operands first, and then decides which value to pick. In your case, the first operand contains a `return`, however, so the function is immediately terminated.

Such a `select` is a special instruction in CPUs to avoid branches. You only want to use it when determining both results is cheaper than performing a branch, like `if` would. Usually, that is the case only when you already have both values, i.e., the first two operands are very simple expressions, like constants or variable reads.